# Routing: Exported variable 'foo' has or is using name 'ModuleWithProviders' from external module

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

i'm following the [angular 2 routes guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FooComponent }    from './component/foo.component';
const fooRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'foopath',  component: FooComponent },
];
export const fooRouting = RouterModule.forChild(fooRoutes);
```

in visual studio code i have the following error:
[image: Typescript Error]
Can anybody tell me why this is happening? That's exactly the same code as the official guide. I'm using the Angular 2 RC5.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should add `import { ModuleWithProviders} from '@angular/core';`

For reference please refer to [ModuleWithProviders](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ModuleWithProviders-interface.html) documentation.

Comment: So this works, but I read the documentation you linked to and I still don't understand WHY it works. My IDE says it isn't used. Could you please explain?

Comment: I just stumbled across this. The reason it works is because your variable fooRouting is of type ModuleWithProviders. The compiler is complaining that the type of your variable fooRouting cannot be found. What you should do is change your declaration to: export const fooRouting: ModuleWithProviders = ...  And then your IDE will know that you are using that type.

Comment: Hi @JordanLapp. for correction you have to write like this 
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes); basically this accept as a type for routing

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same issue. It appeared after I added

```
"declaration": true,
```

in **tsconfig.json** file

If you don't need this option, just remove it.

Comment: can you please brief on this what is role of "declaration"?

Comment: declaration says to Generate corresponding .d.ts file